# How to config django media folders?

Tags: python, django, static, media

I have Django v 3.0.
My [requirements](https://pastebin.com/6uzknQFe).
I try to open media link but I get an error that the path / file doesn't exists.
In my settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "assets")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets', 'media')

STATIC_URL = '/assets/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    STATIC_DIR,
]

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
]

TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR, ],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'django.template.context_processors.media',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

my urls.py

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I don't know how to going on and need your help

Comment: Hi, could you add the stack trace of your error?

Comment: Try adding MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets', 'media') and MEDIA_URL = '/media/' end of the setting.py file.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your configuration.It is placement problem you should not define media root and url before STATICFILES_DIRS.

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "assets")

STATIC_URL = '/assets/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    STATIC_DIR,
]

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
]

TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR, ],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'django.template.context_processors.media',
        ],
    },
},
]
# place this code end of setting 
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets', 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Comment: To help other people please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. When searching answer in stackoverflow people see only up voted and accepted answer.